# How to find which item is selected on DropDownList?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

This is the declaration of resource:

```
public var langs:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(
        [ {lab:"English"},
        {lab:"Russian"}]);
```

This is declaration of dorpdownlist:

```
<s:DropDownList x="157.7" y="10.35" id="list" ></s:DropDownList>
<s:TextArea x="15" y="38" width="255" height="277" id="textG"/>
<s:TextArea x="286" y="39" width="251" height="276" id="textT"/>
<s:Button x="465" y="322.65" label="Translate" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
<s:DropDownList x="286.3" y="10.35" dataProvider="{langs}" labelField="lab" prompt="select"></s:DropDownList>
```

How to find which item is selected on DropDownList via AS3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide an id to the [DropDownList](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DropDownList.html).

```
<s:DropDownList id="dropDownlistID" x="286.3" y="10.35" dataProvider="{langs}" 
                labelField="lab" prompt="select"></s:DropDownList>
```

and get the selected item as

```
dropDownlistID.selectedItem
```

I'm not sure, but if you follow the API then there must be a property called `selectedIndex`. So you can get the item from the `dataprovider`, `ArrayCollection lang` as
`lang.getItemAt(dropDownlistID.selectedIndex);`

Comment: what type is it gonna be? i have an id in the first part of declaration already.

Comment: Your last `s:DropDownList` doesn't have an `id`. It will be of type `Object`.